# MongoDB Aggregation - filter results according to an array of data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want a group of random data of a Connection type schema. But I want to filter the data in accordance with a group of array **'isConnections'** which is a collection of userID's, so that the fetched data does not include any document where its userID is in the **'isConnections' array**.

Initially, I tried using the following logic, and many others that I found over stack overflow, but none worked.

```
"isConnection": [
   "62adca9063bc6adb05d79db8",
   "62af5f3a3920076f461d8a3f",
   "62bfd0935d52cdde5a4e89a9",
   "62b3bb29342af89edcd11264"
]
```

```
let Connections = await ConnectionModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { UserID: { $ne: isConnection } } },
    { $sample: { size: 10 } }
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ne` is looking for an exact match. you want to be using [$nin](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) ( not in ), like so:

```
let Connections = await ConnectionModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { UserID: { $nin: isConnection } } },
    { $sample: { size: 10 } }
])
```

Also just make sure `UserID` is actually `string` type and not `ObjectID`, otherwise you'll have to convert the input array as well.